# Is it possible to make an auto join of tables by foreign keys

Tags: sql-server

**What do i mean?**
I'm looking for elegant way that Sql-engine will join for me automatically columns by keys and relationships that already familiar to the Sql-engine server when I created those tables.

I know I can create query code with inner join for all the tables and mess with to many code (if it's a lot of tables or/and the query is dynamic).

Those who worked with access before probarly noticed that access has a "plus" icon on the result grid which allows to expand the item and see the objects "under" the foreign key.

It looks like that: (In this figure you can see that under the "1" number there are 3 rows on another related table).
[image]

I'm looking the same thing on sql management.

I tried to google about it but I didn't found an expression for that action.

Comment: Indeed, some RDBMSs do allow this out of the box, e.g. http://www.sqlines.com/sybase-asa/key_join

Comment: @RichardHansell Do you familiar with one of those managments?

Comment: I knew this was a "thing" in Sybase but no more that that. I have used reporting products that automatically create data models based on foreign key constraints, etc.  Personally I think key joins are a TERRIBLE idea and I am glad that MSSQL doesn't support this syntax.  I am pretty sure there is no way to get an "Access like" view in SSMS.

Comment: @RichardHansell Why do you think it's terrible? for what reason?

Comment: Some good reasons here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15147/why-arent-primary-key-foreign-key-matches-used-for-joins